# When can I use "while" instead of "when"?

Tags: word-choice

I have been learning English for a long time, but still don't understand about the when/while difference and their usage.

When can I use "while"?

Comment: Just an additional note to the answers you're receiving (which focus on the temporal sense of both words): "while" can be used to show contrast, similarly to "whereas." E.g. I enjoy going backpacking on vacation, while my wife prefers visiting big cities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**While** describes [a length of time.](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/when#word=while)

> If we compare various dictionaries, while is used to talk about an **[unspecific period of time](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/while)**, like  when you ask your friend if you can borrow his notebook for a while.

- at the same time that something is happening

  ```
  While in prison he shared a cell with Ron Spicer.

  Could you look after the children while I cook lunch?
  ```
- used when comparing things, situations, or people

  ```
  While most children learn to read easily, some need extra help.

  The south of the country grows richer, while the north grows poorer.
  ```
- formal used for saying that although you accept that something is true, there are also doubts or facts that you cannot ignore

  ```
  While I agree with you, I do not believe that your way is best.
  ```

Answer (score 2):

@Martin 's answer is generally correct, *when* is a specific moment (you can conceptualize it geometrically as a point), but *while* is a period of time (you can conceptualize it as a line).  It is important to note however, that the "point" of time expressed by *when* may be fuzzy and large.  For that reason it might be better to think of the distinction as being that *while* is generally used for things synchronized in time, where the simultaneous nature of their occurrence is important:

*You can have a cookie **when** the bell rings* means you can have a cookie after the bell signals you.  *You can have a cookie **while** the bell rings* means you need to consume the cookie during the time the bell is ringing.

In the specific case of *when I was a child* it the usage is because we are conceptualizing childhood as a point of time.  Compare ***when*** I was a child, the war was going on with ***while*** I was a child, the war was going on.  The second version emphasizes two simultaneous things happening in parallel, the first locates one thing in relationship to another.  The distinction is subtle, and largely a matter of choice.

Comment: Are these sentences interchangable with no remarkable difference in meaning: "_When_ she was talking, he started to laugh", "_While_ she was talking, he started to laugh", and "_As_ she was talking, he started to laugh"

Answer (score 1):

When generally refers to a specific moment of time, whereas while refers to a period of time.

Comment: So "when I was a child" doesn't refer to a period of time?

Comment: Why do people say "When I was child.." not " While I was child.."?

Comment: People say both, Phil.

Answer (score 1):

When - at that time.
While - during that time.

Answer (score 1):

While implies a continuation of some state whereas when is a single condition.

While I may not be the smartest person in town, I still manage to get by.

When I am not smart in going about doing things, I find it is harder to get by.

Answer (score 0):

Use **While** when you are still doing something or *while* something is happening

Use **When** at the time of doing something or *when* something has happened

Answer (score -2):

You can use *while* while you want to say *when*, and you can use *when* when you want to say *while*.  Clear?

*When pregnant* refers to the condition qua if/then condition

*While pregnant* = refers to pregnancy qua ongoing condition

Since pregnancy is on ongoing condition, "when pregnant" strikes my ear as unidiomatic, but many people use them interchangeably.